# C printf address of a variable

Tags: c

I am a new to programming, in book i find this: Operator '&'- Returns the address of a variable.    &a; returns the actual address of the variable. Ok. But why i can't do this (in commented lines)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

        char a = 'A';
        //int i;

        printf("char a is: %c\n",a);

        //i=&a;
        //printf("adrress  of a is: %d\n",i);
}
```

When compilling i get an error. What is wrong?

Comment: `%p` is the *format specifier* for printing a *pointer* (the address), e.g. `printf("char a is: %p\n",(void *)&a);`

Comment: Because `i` is an `int` type, not a pointer type. Suppose the size of `int` is 4 and the size of a pointer is 8. Can you see a problem?

Comment: yes it's work, thank you! i need read more about pointers, sorry for stupid question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, `%p` is the proper *format specifier* for printing a *pointer* (e.g. address). You can simply rewrite your printf as:

```
printf ("char a is: %p\n", (void*)&a);
```

Also, get in the habit of using the correct declaration for main. It is either `int main (void)` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. `main` is also type `int` and therefore should return a value (the standard defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` (`0`) or `EXIT_FAILURE` (`1`), See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup (draft n1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char a = 'A';

    printf ("char a is: %p\n", (void*)&a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/prnaddr
char a is: 0x7fffa7f84f70
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: Sure, also note, the cast to `(void*)` isn't technically necessary when printing a direct address (e.g. `&a`), but is included to emphasize the `type` for the format specifier `%p` is `(void*)` `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char a = 'A';
        char* i = &a;
        printf("char a is: %c\n", a);
        printf("address of a is: %p\n", &a);
        printf("address of a is: %p\n", i);
        printf("char is: %c\n", *i);
}
```

`a` is a `char` variable with 'A' value. Address of `a` is `&a`.
`char* i` is a pointer which points to `a`. To get value by pointer `*` is used

Comment: `%d` is **not** the correct specifier for printing pointers/addresses

Comment: thanks. changed `%d` to `%p`